# Could this structure be correct: "There is the cleanest park I've been to"?

Tags: sentence-construction, dummy-pronouns

I was asked to say if the sentence "There is the cleanest park I've been to" is correct or no. I said no and it should be "This is the cleanest park I've ever been to".

Then I consulted with some checkspelling machines such as grammarly and quilbot and they didn't flag it as incorrect.

Then I talked to some AI characters and they said that the sentence can't be labled as ungrammatical, and it's a matter of personal preference and suchlike.

So, I'm checking it with you.
I have no more context, but I wonder if it can be correct in some specific contexts, if yes, what for example?

Comment: This implies a cleanest park exist(that you have visited before).

Comment: You do  not necessarily need an "ever" at all.

Answer (score 3):

A sentence can be 'grammatically correct' without making sense or being idiomatic.

We use "There is..." to say that something exists - "There is a park near my house" and "This is..." to refer to something nearby or to the place where we are. So your version is by far the most natural.

Comment: Yup. "There is the cleanest park I've been to" really only works if you're currently pointing right at it.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine riding a train through a city. At one point you notice what neighborhood you are passing through and, pointing out the window, say to your companion, “Look! **There** is the cleanest park I’ve ever been to.”

Comment: Yes, it's deictic.

Comment: I wouldn't say I have 'been to' a park if I have only seen it through a train window.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, nor would I. What I imagined in this example is that the speaker is recounting his earlier experiences. It’s the cleanest park he had been to at the moment of his utterance.

Comment: Thanks, but even in that scenario, I would definitely go for "This is the ... ", simply because I'm pointing out, referring, showing something!

Comment: The choice is yours. I understood you to be asking if the *there* version “could be correct” (see your title) and I provided a context in which it is  indeed be perfectly idiomatic.